# Does copying FoxPro .DBF files affect a running FoxPro application?

Tags: database, foxpro

I want to copy many big FoxPro dbf files (totally >80G) from production environment to a test machine. Those dbf files are business data of a old FoxPro application. This application is running and I cannot stop it.

Can I copy those files? Will it affect the application?

Comment: I'm not sure how this qualifies as a programming question. (Just because you're copying from production to development doesn't make the copy operation programming.) With that being said, it should be fine; the only two things I can see being a problem is that your application has them open exclusively (in which case the copy of that file will fail) or you overwhelm your network by copying so much data. Copying itself is read-only, so it shouldn't require a lock on the file to do so.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends how valid you need the test machine data to be - do you need it exact to test for a problem, or do you just need a copy to play with?

If you need an exact copy then you need to stop the FoxPro application. There is no way round this, because the only way you can ensure that all tables have been written to and closed is by stopping the application.

If you just need a copy to mess around with then I often do this at the prompt using XCOPY with the /Z parameter.

Make sure that the FoxPro application is not being actively used if possible, then if your live data is in c:\mylivedata and you want to copy to c:\mytestdata, at cmd prompt:

xcopy /z /s c:\mylivedata*.* c:\mytestdata

Comment: If the application uses the files EXCLUSIVEly, it won't be possible to copy them at all while the application is running.  If you are able to copy the files, and your intent is to create a local copy of the application, see whether the application has any option to rebuild/repair the indices - it's possible that while copying a running application, that the index files might not be in sync with what's in the DBFs.

Comment: In that case use HoboCopy: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/backupcopy-files-that-are-in-use-or-locked-in-windows/

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I will try it at night when it is most possible time no users are using it.